how to set mobile virtual device in the split window by downloading API in android studio
i want to use android studio in java but i don't how to set up virtual split screen for mobile or other devices by downloading emulator or API. can someone give hints i want to see the changes in my virtual screen as i make changes in the code
some steps to make it work in the Android Studio Jellyfish 2023.3.1
